# Idiomatic way to store and access custom LaTeX code

Tags: init-file, use-package

I have some latex classes or bunch of packages I use and that I'd like to move out of my `init.el` because it keeps on growing and I want them to be standalone.

How can I make them accessible from my init ?

For example would the following structure work :

```
.emacs.d/
    |
    |-------------- init.el
    |-------------- early-init.el
    |-------------- lisp/
    |-------------- snippets/
    |-------------- latex/
                       |
                       |------- templates.el
```

write something (minimal working example) like

```
(require 'ox-latex)

(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
           '("notes"
         "\\documentclass[myLanguage]{article}
\\usepackage{somePackage}
\\usepackage{someOtherPackage}"))

(provide 'templates)
```

and then in my `init.el`

```
(use-package ox-latex
  :after org
  :defer t
  :load-path (concat user-emacs-directory "latex/templates.el")
  :config
  (more-config-stuff...))
```

Would that work or am I painting myself into a corner here?

Comment: Try it and see - I don't foresee any major problems, but I don't know the details of how `use-package` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
(use-package template
  :after org
  :defer t
  :load-path (lambda () (concat user-emacs-directory "latex"))
  :config
  (more-config-stuff...))
```

`(concat user-emacs-directory "latex")` does not get evaluated in use-package, so you can use a function that returns what you need instead.

I am assuming ox-latex is already on your load-path with org-mode, and what you are really trying to do is load templates.el.

Alternatively, just do something like this in init.el

`(load-file (concat user-emacs-directory "latex/templates.el"))`

Comment: Good stuff, I just didn't know how to go about it but that'll make my latex packages and possibly loaded classes (kaobook, tuftex, etc) more portable hopefully. Thanks Pr. Kitchin!